# Hi, If we want to show/hide both tabs and fields in AEM, based on the style selected for a component

Tags: content-management-system, adobe, aem

Like for my one component there a two styles added , if style one is selected then I have to hide 1 field in cq:dialog and if style 2 is selected then I have to show that field

Answer (score 1):

Is the style mentioned above, is a dropdown within same dialog? If yes, there are numerous examples explaining how to implement Show/Hide of dialog fields. Please check [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JZFFxxiFpGY), [here](https://aemhints.com/2020/11/02/show-hide-fields-in-aem-dialog/), [here](http://www.sgaemsolutions.com/2019/01/showhide-tabs-and-fields-based-on-drop.html), [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/aem-hideshow-drop-down-select-options-more-than-one-values-vikraman?articleId=6674275119294230528).

Basically idea is on the dropdown field, add a class `cq-dialog-dropdown-showhide` and a property `cq-dialog-dropdown-showhide-target` with a value of class selector unique to component. Then by defining property `showhidetargetvalue` on the element, selecting the dropdown will show/hide respective properties.

If the style you mentioned is the style system applied using brush icon, it is not OOTB. You ll need to add an authoring clientlib and implement logic to hide specific dialog field based of style system applied.

IMO style system is presentational, only to apply skin to the component. It should not drive business logic of allowing dialog properties. As simplistic, maybe allow authors to enter all allowable fields at dialog and using JS, you may consume / not, the dialog properties.